# Huge datasets for practise

Tags: dataset

I am currently doing a project which requires a dataset. May I know whether there are any free large public datasets that has the following characteristics:

1. greater than 3GB
2. non-tabular (each txt file contains a weblog/ written paragraph)

Answer (score 1):

You can collect research articles. A large subset of the biomedical literature can be downloaded from PubMed:

- [Medline](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/help/#download-pubmed-data) is the full collection of abstracts (around 30 millions).
- [PubMedCentral](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/tools/ftp/) is a subset of around 3 millions full papers (as opposed to containing only the abstract).

Both are very large, more than 50GB as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kaggle and filter all data sets that are greater than 3Gb and that have text content.

The data is generally speaking free, but a subscription is needed and there are some rules to follow.

For instance:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?sizeStart=3000%2CMB&tags=14104-Text+Data

Answer (score 1):

Two sources which have not been mentioned yet are [Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/datasets) and [Papers with code](https://paperswithcode.com/datasets). While you cannot filter for dataset disk space, Huggingface allows filtering for dataset size in terms of datapoints/rows. The English [Wikipedia dataset](https://huggingface.co/datasets/wikipedia), for example, is about 20GB (and requires 40GB disk space).

Comment: Minor correction: according to that page Wikipedia (20220301.en) is 20GB (and requires 40GB disk space).

Comment: Thanks, @DarrenCook - I have edited my answer accordingly.